# Re-use the jquery dialog modal popup across the project with various content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a requirement where jquery modal popup (skeleton) should be re-usable only the content inside the dialog should change probably using partial view.

I have a partialview with modal popup skeleton ( intention is i want to re-use this code across the project)

On click of jqgrid column image i trigger a function

function RenderModalPopup(rowid, tableid, event) {
    debugger;

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Edit/GetPopupPartial',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        $('#showDialog').load(data);
 }
});
```

which i will call a action method which inturn will load partial view

Comment: Partial view content <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#showDialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 800
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="showDialog">
</div>

Comment: Not sure how to achieve this re-usable modal popup requirement. Could anyone please suggest an approach. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

create a common js like common.js and put the function in it

```
function RenderModalPopup(rowid, tableid, event) { debugger;
```

$.ajax({
    url: '/Edit/GetPopupPartial',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        $('#showDialog').load(data);
 }
});

and call the function from any page like

RenderModalPopup();